# Exception thrown by CAKE during TeamCity build but not reproducible locally

Tags: c#, powershell, teamcity, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.22.0.

In one of my build steps, I added a `Finally` clause. Inside `Finally`, I call the `RunPowershellScript` method that in turn executes a Powershell script residing in version control.

When testing in my local clone of the main source repository, everything runs successfully, with no exceptions thrown at any stage.

However, on TeamCity, the `RunPowershellScript` method threw `System.NullReferenceException` with the error message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`:

[image]

I logged into my build agent and was able to verify with 100% confidence that the PowerShell script ran without issue.

Questions:
 1. **Why did it throw an exception, even though the PowerShell script was executed successfully on the build agent?**
 2. Why am I unable to reproduce the error locally?

### Addendum 1:

In response to [Matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771517/exception-thrown-even-though-operation-was-successful?noredirect=1#comment80490570_46771517) I decided to check whether my script was throwing any non-terminating error by setting `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop`.

My script ran to completion without throwing any error (terminating or otherwise) on my local machine. When I logged into my build agent, I could also see that the script had run successfully to completion. So what I truly don't understand now is **why the build failed on TeamCity even though the PowerShell script ran 100% fine**.

### Addendum 2:

After another build failure on a remote build agent (with the same exception thrown), I logged on again to investigate. In my Powershell script, I have a dictionary wherein the keys are `string`s and the values `string[]`s. I also have a `for` loop that enumerates through all the values for a supplied key.

*This time*, I was able to verify that **enumeration stopped after the first item in the array**, and the exception was thrown at this point. Previously, the exception was thrown even though all items in the array were enumerated through. Is there a bug in the Powershell add-in for CAKE?

When I tested the Powershell script by calling it directly (i.e., *not* by using CAKE's Powershell add-in), enumeration through all the values completed without any hiccup. When I tested it by running `build.cake` on my local machine, it also ran successfully to completion.

So it seems to me that the exception message was thrown by CAKE only during TeamCity builds, regardless of whether the PowerShell script was executed successfully or not.

Comment: ... `System.NullReferenceException` with the error message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` So the problem is in the script then? You somehow have a null created in there.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your reply. I am 100% confident that the script is fine -- I logged into the build agent and was able to verify that the script ran successfully to completion. What I don't understand is why CAKE threw an error when everything ran smoothly.

Comment: So you think it is from the calling process? The script could still do what you wanted it to _and_ throw that error to the error stream if it was a non terminating error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Matt. That was a possibility I hadn't considered.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have verified that my script is **not** throwing any non-terminating error by setting ``$ErrorActionPreference`` to ``Stop``. It executed successfully to completion.

Comment: @My_G Running locally on the agent doesn't accurately replicate things like the working directory that TeamCity can sometimes override on things. Print some logging information in your Cake file about where it thinks you are, you may find that it works locally because things can be resolved correctly that cannot be resolved when an environmental factor changes. Also, review things like PowerShell version and .NET Framework runtime versions.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that TeamCity is looking for a return code from the poweshell script. You may need to have it return a 0.

You can do this by adding:

```
EXIT 0;
```

to the end of your script. If 0 doesn't work, try a 1.